# Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am creating a chart application in jsp... am storing form values in javascript variables and i need to pass these values to jQuery highchart variables.... please can someone help me how to do this..

here is my javascript function in 'home.jsp':

```
function printValues(oSel)
                {
                     plant=document.getElementById("plantId");
                     plant_text=plant.options[plant.selectedIndex].text;
                     plant_value=document.getElementById("plantId").value;

                 period=document.getElementById("periodId");
                 period_text=period.options[period.selectedIndex].text;
                 period_value=document.getElementById("periodId").value;

                    interval=document.getElementById("intervalId");                        interval_text=interval.options[interval.selectedIndex].text;                    
                 interval_value=document.getElementById("intervalId").value;


                 len=oSel.options.length;                     
                 for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
                 {
                     if(oSel.options[i].selected)
                     {                             
                         data+="\n"+ oSel.options[i].text + "["+ "\t" +  Sel.options[i].value + "]";                             
                     }
                 }
                 if(data!="")
                 {
                     alert("The selected Items are :" + data);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     alert("There are no selected items");
                 }

                 title=document.chart.chartTitle.value;
            }
```

and my barchart.jsp file have following code:

```
         var chart;
         $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.barchart').click(function(barTitle) {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                        'Jan',
                        'Feb',
                        'Mar',
                        'Apr',
                        'May',
                        'Jun',
                        'Jul',
                        'Aug',
                        'Sep',
                        'Oct',
                        'Nov',
                        'Dec'
                    ]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 100,
                    y: 70,
                    floating: true,
                    shadow: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return ''+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                    series: [{
                    name: 'Tokyo',
                    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

                }, {
                    name: 'New York',
                    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

                }, {
                    name: 'London',
                    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

                }, {
                    name: 'Berlin',
                    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

                }]
            });
        });
                     });
```

i need to pass those title, plant_value, period_value to chart title, xaxis, yaxis variable... please can someone help me how to pass javascript values to jquery variable values?

thanks in advance

Comment: Pardon me, but what's a `.jsp` file? I know of Java Server Pages but that's a completely differnt story. Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: @aefxx: what we're seeing is just a part of a Java Server Pages file.

Comment: @darioo Inline scripting, that is? Thanks for clearifying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happens when, but can't you just use `title: {text: document.chart.chartTitle.value}` and things like that? That way, you will always use the most recent data in your chart at the moment you click the $('.barchart') item.

Or, staying in jQuery form, `title: {text: $('form[name=chart] input[name=chartTitle]').val()}`

Finally, if 'title' et al. are global variables, you can use `title: {text: title}`. Note that if you haven't declared `title` as a global variable at the moment printValues sets it, a global variable will be introduced anyway.

Comment: really thanks spiny.. your answer helps me a lot... but both are in different jsp pages.. javascript in 'home.jsp' and jQuery chart is in 'barchart.jsp'...

Comment: Ok, then I guess you'll have to get them into the same page :) Actually, it would seem you don't need the javascript part (the printValues function) to do what you're trying to do. Is the html form containing the chart data available in the barchart.jsp as well?

Comment: No. It will be displayed in the same page, after clicking the submit button. I have to pass the selected 'data' array values to database have to pass these retrieved values to 'series' in jquery chart. Can you tell some ideas on how i have to pass values dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question to this at the below link. Hope it helps.

[Display Highcharts data from mysql database on jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930195/display-highcharts-data-from-mysql-database-on-jsp-page)