# Display Highcharts data from mysql database on jsp page

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp, highcharts

I want to use Highcharts (master/detail example) to display data in .jsp page. Data will dynamically be loaded from mysql database. Does anyone has example on how to do this. Any suggestion, starting from scratch would help, even most basic, meaning you can suggest any data to show on most simplest jsp page.

I appreciate your time and help.
Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/133242)

Comment: Highcharts web site [http://www.highcharts.com/] is having samples. Did you take a look?

Comment: Matt: thanks. I did configure highcharts with static data to load, I just need some advice in regard of mysql database.

Comment: Sandeep: I did implement highcharts statically, but I need to get data from mysql db. thx,

Answer (score 1):

You have probably already found the solution for that. If not however this is it.

1) You will need a JDBC connection in your JSP in the form of a <% %> scriptlet or even better a servlet. Im using SQLITE for ease.

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/DBlocation/Dbname");
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
```

2) You then want to parse the result via ResultSet into an ArrayList

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    // Query DB for dates
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select distinct(date) from project_time;");
    while (rs.next()) 
      { 
         al.add(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
      } 
    rs.close();
```

3) Next you want to pass this ArrayList back to your JSP Page using RequestDispatcher

```
RequestDispatcher rd = null;

request.setAttribute("values",al);
rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("chart.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

4) On your jsp page you want to get the values passed from your servlet as below and pass them to an iterator

```
ArrayList valuelist=(ArrayList)request.getAttribute("values");
Iterator valueIterator = valuelist.iterator();
```

5) Next you need to loop through the iterator in your javascript to generate your graph values.

```
xAxis: {
                    categories: 
                        [<% while(valueIterator.hasNext()) { out.println("'"+ valueIterator.next() +"',");} %>],                    
                    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                    title: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
```

And thats about it. Hopefully that is clear enough, if not flick me a message and I will help you out further.

Comment: Use FTL and Highcharts from your servlet.