# Passing an array from jsp to java script

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, highcharts

I am working on this website and came across some difficulties. I connect to the database using JSP, and display the data using **JAVASCRIPT**. So I want to transfer an entire array from JSP part of a code to java script part of the code. I tried to transfer a string - and even that I failed.

Of course a seached the web and seems like it is not that easy to do, just as well as to connect to database using java script.

Here I want to copy the values from int[] intArray={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12} - created an array to try without loading values from database in JSP to `var array[];` in JAVASCRIPT.

Or maybe there is an easier way to copy data from database to highcharts!?
Please help!!!

small part of JSP code:

```
<%!
String jdbcDriver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
String jdbcURL    = "jdbc:postgresql:IrishClimateData";
String user       = "postgres";
String password   = "postgres";
int[] intArray={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

%>
```

Java Script:

```
$(function () {
var chart;
var array[];
var arr1 = [-2, 8, 5, 11, 17, 22, 24, 24, 20, 14, 8, 2];
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: arr1
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: You can just print text from your jsp. Javascript is text as well. So, just print the array with the proper javascript syntax.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I dont want to print the text, I need to pass the values from JSP and display them using java script. The values have to come from JSP, since they will be loaded from database - here I created an array myself to simplify at first!

Comment: Have you tried to export data from JSP as JSON ?

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this question in detail at the below link. Hopefully it helps.

[Display Highcharts data from mysql database on jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930195/display-highcharts-data-from-mysql-database-on-jsp-page)

Answer (score 0):

Assigne the intArray to var array[] in java script using scriptlets like var array[] = "<%=intArray%>";

Answer (score 0):

U can write something like this maybe:

first assign the arrays's elements to a string with commas like:

```
String a="1,2,3,4,5";
```

then assign it to another variable:

```
var arrayStr=<%=a%>;
```

then do this:

```
var array=arrayStr.split(',');
```

hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON, it is pure javascript syntax so when you receive it in javascript you can use it as a javascript object.

JSON:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

JSON in jsp:
[Creating a json object in jsp and using it with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046331/creating-a-json-object-in-jsp-and-using-it-with-jquery) (it is not necessary to use jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

First, load your java array from the database. I just hardcoded `{1, 2, 3}` for the sake of argument.

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
```

Print this to the javascript variable `array`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<%
    out.println("var array = " + a);
%>
</script>
```

Now you can use `array` in your javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was able to use out.println("var array = " + a[0]); to copy one element and print it ous, since ("var array = " + a) did not work. However I was no able to copy an array... I tried this: for( var i = 0; i<12; i++){ out.println("var array["+ i + "] = " + a[i]) and simple out.println("var array[i] = " + a[i]) did not work either... Is there any way to copy an entire array? Do you know? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Andrei Ivanov I can't test this now,  but can you try `("var array = " + Arrays.toString(a))`?

Answer (score 0):

te right answer is-
abc.jsp

```
<html>
function call()
{
var name="xyz";
window.location.replace("abc.jsp?name="+name);
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Get" onclick='call()'>
<%
String compose1=request.getParameter("name");
out.println(name);
%>    </html>
```

it works in my program, hope you it will help you too...